# React Native: react-native-image-picker is not triggering the callback for launchImageLibrary

Tags: react-native

I am building a mobile application using React Native. My application needs to access photo library and camera. I am using this library, https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker. I could launch the photo library, but when I selected the photo, it is not triggering the callback function.

Here is my code:

```
const renderPreviewImage = () => {
        if (! photoUri) {
            return null
        }

        return (
            <Image
                resizeMode={"cover"}
                resizeMethod={"scale"}
                style={{width: 200, height: 200}}
                source={{uri: photoUri}}
                />
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <Button label={"Select Photo"} onPress={() => {
                launchImageLibrary({
                    mediaType: "photo"
                }, (response) => {
                    console.log('This is not triggered')
                })
            }} />
            {renderPreviewImage()}
        </View>
    )
```

as you can see the comment in the code, the callback was not called. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Button's onPress:

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: false,
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      //This is the image being returned
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
// This how you display the image in your main component below:
    {image && (
                  <Image source={{ uri: image }}
                    style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }} />
                )}
```